# Getting total amount of memory, available in Adobe Flash from ActionScript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, memory

I have to load a lot of data from BlazeDS and/or Livecycle DS service to Adobe Flex and would like to find out what's available from memory stand point.  This is similar to querying in java: *long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find the available memory, but you can find the memory currently in use via the `System.totalMemory` property.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/system/System.html#totalMemory